# Official 7in display touchscreen not working

Tags: display, touchscreen

I just got my official touchscreen in the mail.

I plugged it in and the display works fine, but the the touch is not working.

I did everything said here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK-w-wDvRTg
and here
http://www.mkcastor.com/2015/09/10/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-setup-review-and-case-design/
(minus usb power instead of the jumpers)

In the second article it mentions that if the touchscreen is not working I should try rebooting.

I have tried:

- `sudo reboot -n`
- disconnecting the power to reboot
- disassembling everything and assembling it again
- tried `apt-get update, upgrade, reboot`

Anyone have any thoughts on what else I can try?
(I am using a rasbpi B+ v1.2 vanilla Raspbian)

**Edit:**
I have now tried it on a PI Model 2 B and the touch screen works fine. However, my B+ still does not work with the touch screen though.

Comment: Could you edit your question and summarise what you have tried.  It's expecting too much of people to trawl through youtube videos and tutorials on your behalf.  Have you done a recent sudo apt get update, sudo apt-get upgrade?  Have you done sudo rpi-update?

Comment: sudo rpi-update?

Comment: May be is simple broken. My display did not work completely

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with display in general. I tried to update etc, but did not work until reinstall particular libraries following [official tutorial](http://forums.pimoroni.com/t/official-7-raspberry-pi-touch-screen-faq/959).
Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-{bin,dev,doc} raspberrypi-bootloader
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to the official tutorial, I hadn't seen it, and it suggested the fix to my issue (for using the original model A or B, you need to add connections to the i2c pins and modify config.txt)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  I got it working with a Raspberry Pi 4 and the Legacy Buster OS.

Now for the story:  I followed the instructions to connect the screen to the board to the RPi.  I installed the Official Raspberry Pi Imager and used the "Recommended" Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Bullseye port) (32 Bit), released 2021-10-30.  When I plugged it in, there was some lights on the RPi flashing, but the it wasn't getting enough power to work.  I unplugged the USB from the monitor and used an official RPi USB-C plug to power the RPi and everything turned on (with a white screen, see the last paragraph) and the RPi would react to touches, but any tap would just click on the lower-right corner of the screen (Plugging in a mouse and wiggling it made the cursor show up again).  I installed the Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) (Debian Buster), released 2021-12-02 and the screen worked perfectly and reacted to touches right after installation.  I can even work the initial "Raspberry Pi setup" screen!

Also, I couldn't get the screen to work at all (No image, to touch, nothing) when I tried to use a RPi 1 with the Bullseye OS.  I could get HDMI output from it and could power the RPi 1 from the monitor, but nothing showed up on the screen.  I didn't pursue it any further because it seemed to be steps in the wrong direction for me (this was before I tried switching the OS).

One last thing: with the Bullseye OS, the display looked like it was suffering from a power surge (the display turned white in a way that did not look healthy) when the RPi 4 first booted, but the effect went away and the screen displayed the desktop.  With the Legacy OS, this problem went away and it behaves like a normal tablet screen.

I'm sorry for the long post, but I didn't want to skip anything important!